# Is it a bug when a tag is seen through a concealed spoiler?

Tags: support, bug, tags, spoilers

I was just looking through pages with dead images, and stumbled upon the [darth-vader](/questions/tagged/darth-vader)  [tag page](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/darth-vader/info) on Science Fiction and Fantasy. Here's what I saw:

[image: tag is seen through spoiler]

Is this just me? Is this a bug, or is it by design?

---

*Just in case, I use latest Opera on Ubuntu 16.04*

Comment: This is a known thing, and it's universal. Not sure whether SE sees it as a bug or by design, but either way it's probably a question for main meta rather than here.

Comment: Migrated. Good luck ;-)

Comment: The correct solution here is to not use spoiler tags for information that's three decades old. [There's a statute of limitations on this s***](https://www.penny-arcade.com/comic/2005/12/05).

Comment: @JoshCaswell the [consensus on SFF](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/980/70236) reads that age of the material is irrelevant - there will always be people new to even Star Wars.

Comment: @Gallifreyan Or people who refuse to watch Star Wars.

Comment: @randal'thor go back to the shadow!

Comment: @JoshCaswell It's Rand al'Thor this should be addressed to :) And I don't think he said that because he minded _Star Wars_ spoilers :)